# Windmill 3 Phase AC control PCB

Tags: power, rectifier, generator, three-phase, buck-boost

I've created a PCB for my newly built 3D printed Windmill. Now I am not entirely sure about all the components and the way they function, so I'd like to have your opinion on the circuitry before I place my order.

The idea is that the circuitry charges an **externaly protected and managed** 18650 and stores sudden current spikes inside the a capacitor (C1). The battery management circuitry requires a voltage of 3.7V and specifies 9A max (Aliexpress protector board, so I'm expecting around 4.5A max charging current)
The board should be able to recover from a total black-out using only the the generator's power.

I expect a maximum of 20V@6A to ever come from the BLDC under load, which will probably only occur during a tornado. You can find the BLDC [here](https://aliexpress.com/item/32834130958.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dvEScG2).

[image: Windmill Schematic]

[image: 5V Regulation circuitry]
[image: 3.7V Regulation circuitry]

The schematic requires some comments.

The power from the BLDC comes in through connector J2 and goes through a diode rectifier bridge (D3-D8)
In order to have the capability to slow the BLDC down, I've added three 0.22 Ohm power resistors in combination with a N-Channel mosfet (Q2) to control the speed of the motor in a high wind force push event.

To enable/disable charging another N-channel mosfet (Q1) is used, but as I'm writing this down I am wondering if this should be a P-Channel mosfet. This mosfet might be used for MPPT.

To get the voltage of the current spike caps, a voltage divider is used (R4-R6).

A current sensor is integrated onto the PCB to monitor the current.

U3 is the 5V system power supply, which provides power to the MCU and various sensors. The idea is that this power supply is able to wakeup on it's own, without the MCU running. ([WeBench](https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=8BDB047EA3CA84C8))

U4 is the battery power supply, which converts the input voltage to 3.7V. ([WeBench](https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=3C967BFA6477601C))

A temperature sensor is also present to monitor the temperature inside the windmill.

The connectors:

- BT1: the battery connection terminals.
- J2: the 3 phase BLDC input.
- J3: the magnetic sensor header for the BLDC.
- J4: the UART header.
- J5: the ICSP header.
- J6: the 433 MHz radio transmit module.

[image: Windmill PCB 3D Top view]
[image: Windmill PCB 3D Bottom view]

The screw terminals visible are not the ones that will be used.

There is a cut-out between the current in and current out pins of the ACS712 which also goes underneath the chip it self.
The 3 pin mosfets use the tap for the drain instead of pin 2, the solder mask has been removed underneath the taps.

Those big blocks next to the diode bridge are the power resistors that dump the energy when needed.

I ran the DRC and everything is solved and passes the checks.

My questions;

- Have I implemented the mosfets properly (I don't mean the mosfets used around U3 and U4)
- What do you think of the schematic and the PCB?
- Do you spot any cricital faults?

Block diagram

[image: Windmill block diagram]

Comment: Asking people here to review your design seems like a lot to ask. This site is supposed to be for specific questions.  The schematic would be easier to follow if the power circuit was drawn out with power flow left to right and all the power connections drawn point to point rather than with several sections with named inputs and outputs. A single-line block diagram would help others to understand the control scheme. Is the braking circuit supposed to limit the motor speed in the event a high wind pushes the speed to the limit, you have 20 V output and the battery is fully charged?

Comment: @Charles Cowie, I'm aware of that fact! The brakes are indeed used when the motor goes too fast or if the system can't put it's energy inside the battery anymore.

Comment: How many watts are R8-R10 capable of dissipating?

Comment: Each one is labeled with 5W, so that is 15W in total. But I think I can get away with this, if I can get the blades to stop spinning completely, I won't need a huge amount of dissipation. I can solder addition resistors to the top of each resistors if needed, they have pins that vertically go through the resistor

Comment: If you pack the resistors close together they will get pretty hot and that area of the PCB will also get pretty hot. If the turbine is producing full power and you try to shut it down, it will take a lot of torque to do that. Another question is current control for charging C1. Do you use Q1 to do that? Also, why are C11-C14 in series?

Comment: I'll try to bent the resistors over a little to spread the heat. Q1 can be used to control the current going into the capacitor so that should be fine, is Q1 correctly used being an N-Channel mosfet? C11-C14 are the output ripple smoothing caps (I think) they are in the webench design

Comment: The question about C11-C14 is why they are series connected. Series connection of capacitors is more than a little unusual. I think you may need a lot more help than I can provide.

Comment: Aah I see! I misread the description of the WeBench design, I'll reduce the caps to only one cap. I've been able to simulate the circuitry and the energy dump is working as expected. The charge mosfet simulation is still running. Thanks for your help! I really appriciate it!

Comment: @CharlesCowie I've updated the schematics in the question and added a block diagram! Are you able to follow my system design a little more now?

Comment: The new position of Q1 could control charging of C1, but no longer controls the input to U3. My original understanding that Q1 determines whether or not BT1 is charged by connecting or disconnecting U3. The value and position of C1 indicates it is suppose to smooth the ripple voltage at the 3-ph rectifier. I would think that it should be directly across the rectifier before the current sensor.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I'm in doubt if I should keep C1, it was used as place for sudden generator energy spikes to be stored, but calculations show that it is basically useless. U3 is controlled via the EN pin, that get's pulled high to the rectifier voltage. I am using D2 to prevent clamp the 20V into 5V, but I don't think that I am using it correctly. The 328P should be able to pull the signal up and pull the signal down.

Comment: Given that a 3-phase rectifier doesn't have very much ripple, C1 could certainly be quite a bit smaller. The TI LM5141 user's guide evaluation module schematic does show some filtering on the input power. The VCC and HB connections are different.

Comment: @CharlesCowie wow yeah! VCC and HB should not have been connected. I made some changes to the PCB and it basically ruined my whole layout.. so I still have some massive rerouting to do